# Smoothness of solutions to wave equation in a bounded domain

Tags: regularity, wave-equation

Consider the wave equation
\begin{equation}
\partial_t^2 u - \sum \partial^2_{x_i} u =0 
\end{equation}
in a bounded domain $M$ with $C^\infty$ boundary, and the boundary conditons
\begin{equation}
u(t,x) = 0, \partial_n u(t,x) =0 ,\ x\in \partial M
\end{equation}
and ifinitely smooth initial values
\begin{equation}
u(0,x), \partial_t u(0,x). 
\end{equation}

Is it true that the solution remains infinitely smooth for all times? If so, what is the proof, if not , what are the counterexamples?

Comment: If you replace "smooth" by "analytic" then there are quantitative versions of Cauchy Kovalevsky. See eg Hormander's *The Analysis of Linear Partial Differential Operators I* Theorem 9.4.5.

Comment: You have too many boundary conditions, so typically there won't be any solution. Without the condition $\partial_n u =0$ it would be a standard initial value problem $d^2u/dt^2=\Delta u$ for the Dirichlet Laplacian on $M$.